# What device information can I access from the Hololens at run time? (OS Level, Serial Code etc)

Tags: c#, hololens, mrtk

What device information can I access from the Hololens at run time using MRTK?

Can MRTK determine a unique identifier for each Hololens device that runs my program? Ideally this would be a serial code, but any other unique identifier from the device would be useful.

I am trying to determine ways to track how many unique devices are running my program, as well as how often they run it.

I am aware that using a managed device might be one way to do this, but I am curious if there is any way to get such information without needing to set up ID Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the instance of the [**`EasClientDeviceInformation`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation) to get device information from the local device. The property [**`Id`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id) provides the identifier of the local device. you can use the following code:

```
using Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning;
. . .
EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
var deviceIdentifier = deviceInfo.Id;
```

In addition, you can retrieve more device information through other properties of the instance, a specific sample is provided here: [Client Device Information sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ClientDeviceInformation).

Comment: I am still familiarizing myself with MRTK and UWP, and I wasn't aware of this option or the samples you linked.This is very helpful.